# R2dbc H2 issues when using inMemory database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I was trying to taste R2dbc and using Embedded H2 like:

```java
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        //ConnectionFactory factory = ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:h2:mem:///test?options=DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        return new H2ConnectionFactory(
                H2ConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        //.inMemory("testdb")
                        .file("./testdb")
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password").build()
        );
    }
```

And I defined a bean to create tables and init data.

```java
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));
        populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("data.sql")));
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);

        return initializer;
    }
```

And I also defined another Component to set up data by java codes.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
class DataInitializer {

    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public DataInitializer(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
        this.databaseClient = databaseClient;
    }

    @EventListener(value = ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        log.info("start data initialization  ...");
        this.databaseClient.insert()
            .into("posts")
            //.nullValue("id", Integer.class)
            .value("title", "First post title")
            .value("content", "Content of my first post")
            .map((r, m) -> r.get("id", Integer.class))
            .all()
            .log()
            .thenMany(
                this.databaseClient.select()
                    .from("posts")
                    .orderBy(Sort.by(desc("id")))
                    .as(Post.class)
                    .fetch()
                    .all()
                    .log()
            )
            .subscribe(null, null, () -> log.info("initialization done..."));
    }

}
```

If I used `.inMemory("testdb")` in the `ConnectionFactory` bean definition, when the Spring `ApplicationContext` is initialized, it failed because **can not find table `POSTS`** when initializing `DataInitializer`. From the startup logging, `ConnectionFactoryInitializer` is initialized successfully, and table **POSTS** is created and data is inserted as expected by executing the schema.sql and data.sql.

But switching to use `.file("./testdb")`, it worked.

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/data-r2dbc/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer from Spring Data R2dc developer, @mp911de. see [#issue269](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/269)

> The issue is related to H2‘s behavior to close the database when the last connection gets closed. Please configure the DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 option so H2 retains the database. Alternatively, use the H2ConnextionFactory.inMemory(...) factory method to create a Closeable connection factory that does not depend on the in-use connection count.

Change my codes to the following, it works:

```java
 public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {       
     return H2ConnectionFactory.inMemory("testdb");
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

From the official documentation

[ConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#r2dbc.connectionfactory)

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return …;
  }
}
```

> This approach lets you use the standard io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory
> instance, with the container using Spring’s
> AbstractR2dbcConfiguration. As compared to registering a
> ConnectionFactory instance directly, the configuration support has the
> added advantage of also providing the container with an
> ExceptionTranslator implementation that translates R2DBC exceptions to
> exceptions in Spring’s portable DataAccessException hierarchy for data
> access classes annotated with the @Repository annotation.
>
> (...)
>
> **AbstractR2dbcConfiguration also registers DatabaseClient, which is required for database interaction and for Repository implementation.**

I have written a blog post about how to set get started with R2DBC [here](https://medium.com/@thomasandolf/r2dbc-getting-started-d0afcfc05be2). [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-r2dbc) is an example using the H2 database

My guess is that you are not initialising the connection factory correctly and hence not getting a proper DatabaseClient.

Comment: I do not think so. From the startup logging, the `ConnectionFactory` is ok, and `ConnectionFactoryInitializer` init successfully(create and insert data), but when init `DataInitializer` to insert another data, failed due to not found table "posts". I mentioned using `.file("./testdb")` instead of `InMemory`, it works.

Comment: well apparently it doesn't otherwise you wouldn't have written here.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf , in your article you mentioned an application.properties using postgresql, but: How Can we use the application.properties with H2DB?

Comment: If you don’t set the properties, the application will default to using H2DB